# Closing connectionSocket throwing 'Invalid syntax with except IOError'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried executing this code, but am getting an error message saying "Invalid syntax".
Please help me out, since am new to this.

```
#import socket module
from socket import *

connectonSocket.close()
except IOError:             
connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n\n')
#Close client socket
connectionSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: You need to indent code and also this code is not complete there should be a try clause before the except and the connect needs to be opened.

Comment: Read: [Handling Exceptions in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)

Answer (score 3):

Please see this informative [TutorialsPoint page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm) for a great explanation of try/except/else/finally Python code!

Your code should be:

```
#import socket module
from socket import *

try:
    connectonSocket.open()
except IOError:             
     connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n\n')
#Close client socket
finally:
    connectionSocket.close()
    serverSocket.close()
```

And if you are copying and pasting your code into `cmd`/`terminal` you cannot have blank lines (If you do you'll get an indentation error).

**`try/except/finally`**

**TRY**:
Means to 'try' to do something, ie. call a function, method, etc.

**EXCEPT** (you can have ***multiple*** excepts):
Means if your 'try' code did NOT work, do 'this' in response.

**FINALLY**:
Means do 'this' stuff whether or not you `'tried' and succeeded`, or `'excepted'`.

Comment: really a close in the try block surely an open there

Comment: +1: It would be nice to explain to OP as well the `try-except` block and not only fix his code. :)

Comment: @BK, thanks for the tip/+1. I went back and supplied a link which helped me learn as well as a brief explanation of my own :)

Comment: No worries. Simple answer and simple explanation. :) Normally, wouldn't push for someone to explain the above as well, but seeing as OP used `except` but didn't have `try` means he probably got the code from somewhere else and edited it himself. :) Good job!